# How to do Logging in Prism 8.1 WPF apllication

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, prism

**Migration from Prism 6.3 to Prism 8.1**

During migration to Prism 8.1, I can't able to find equivalent Logging functionality.
Is there any Logging functionality in Prism 8.1 ?
If not there how we can use `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging` library ?

I have tired to find the equivalent Logging in official website [https://prismlibrary.com/docs](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), But I didn't get. Even tried to implement the  `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging` library, But the `PrismBootStraper` class not supporting.

Comment: We use log4net in our Prism app.  Just add the nuget package, give the application assembly a .config file for it, st that up with an assembly attribute and you're off to the races.   I put my own logging interface around it and inject that via Prism

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your response, But I have to use  **Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging** Library.

Comment: Well I do see a bunch of NuGet Packages for EnterpriseLibrary in the NuGet Package manager including one for logging.  They seem to be recently updated.  Have you tried using them?.  Also you should be aware that with Prism 8.x you do not use a BootStrapper.  You are supposed to derive your application class from `PrismApplication `and all the stuff that used to happen in the Boostrapper should happen there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can't  we use PrismBootstrapper class from Prism.DryIoc instead of PrismApplication class from Prism.WPF?
I Have tried using 3rd party logger Serilog by registering it in Prism Container but due to dependency WRT to Enterprise logging of other project, I reconsidered using Enterprise logging but unable to find the proper implementation.

Comment: I cannot tell you what is possible.  Maybe what you want is possible.  Maybe not.  I can only tell you what you are *supposed* to do.  If you truly want to update your app to Prism 8.1,  you are supposed to derived your application from `PrismApplication` and move your bootstrapper code to the functions that you override.  It's a pretty straightforward conversion.  And who knows maybe it will solve the issues you are having with logging.